# jquery find element in string and replace for something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I want to do is get new Date():

```
Wed Oct 02 2013 22:15:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

And replace the `22:15:00` for something else...

Is that possible using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a generic solution. You could go for a regex based solution. But lets keep it simple.

What you have in hand is a Date object right? The Date object supports methods like `setHours()`, `setMinutes()` and `setSeconds()`. Use them to change the time!

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
'Wed Oct 02 2013 22:15:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'.replace(/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/, '00:00:00')
```

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'replace'" any idea why?

Comment: I'm doing this `var l = new Date;` then `l.replace(/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/, '00:00:00')`

Comment: @Darkagelink in that case see the next answer by  stevaity ... use `l.setHours(0); l.setMinutes(0); l.setSeconds(0);`